# Error on .ini file trying to run supervisord

Tags: mac-osx, supervisord

I am trying to use http://supervisord.org/. But came across and error. I have the `supervisord.conf` file in the same directory I am running this in.

I tried to run `supervisord` for the first time on my OSX Lion computer and when I run it I get the error:

`Error: .ini file does not include supervisord section`

I installed it via `easy_install` just like the instructions say. Cannot really find anything helpful in a Google search. Help and direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have the supervisord section in the config file. When it said .ini file, it threw me off.

Comment: hardly surprising, this is a misleading error!

Comment: So what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please note the [supervisorctl] section. It may be added together with [rpcinterface:supervisor] and [unix_http_server] which were part of a solution for a socket issue when using supervisor 3.x: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/480

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[unix_http_server]
file = /var/run/supervisor.sock

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock

[program:install-env]
command=bash -c "cp /opt/env/ln-env.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a line with `[supervisord]` to your config file will be enough.